# Create a Laravel Blade Form with no action

Tags: javascript, php, forms, laravel, laravel-blade

I want to create a Laravel Blade Form with no action. I want to handle all with JavaScript. In HTML I would do:

```
<form action="#">
```

or

```
<form action="javascript:void(0)">
```

How can I do them in Laravel Blade Form, like this:

```
{{Form::open()}}
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: would it matter  try  this when you submit the form run the javascript function and at the end use return false; or if you are using jquery use event.preventDefault(); but donot forget to pass the event object i.e the event or whtever you want to name it this prevents the submission of form

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! Now I will use event.preventDefault() and return false every time I use jQuery Ajax in Form, and don't care about the action url in the Form Open!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do this

```
{{ Form::open(['url' => '#']) }}
```

Answer (score 0):

After all, the form builder just helps you generate a form. You don't *have* to use it. In your case I'd just write it in plain HTML:

```
<form action="javascript:void(0)">
```

To add the csrf token just use:

```
{{ Form::token() }}
```

Comment: I am afraid that by doing so, we cannot create the _token in laravel blade Form!

Comment: The answer is nice! This will help me! Thank you!